# formatting amount

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am fetching data from a web service. I am using ASP.NET and VB.NET as code behind.

I tried like this:

```
Label_amount.Text = Trim(arData(11))
```

I am getting the output as *0020000*, while I should get *200*, i.e. suppress all leading zeros and delete last two zeros. (or make as 200.00)

Comment: If it's always numeric just use `Int32.Parse(arData(11))`. This will get rid of the leading zeros, but 20000 is NOT 200.00, for this you'll have to divide.

Comment: `Trim` only removes leading and trailing white space... you need something different... maybe try parse and divide by 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, if it is displaying as "0020000", that must mean that `arData(11)` is a `String`.  If it's supposed to always be a numeric value, it would be best to parse it into a numeric data type, such as `Integer` or `Decimal`.  Once you have the value stored as a numeric type, you can easily manipulate it (such as dividing by 100) and format it as desired.  For instance:

```
Dim value As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(arData(11))
value = Value / 100
Label_amount.Text = value.ToString("N2")
```

Keep in mind that the `Parse` method will throw an exception if `arData(11)` does not contain a valid numeric value, so you may want to wrap it with a try/catch, or use the `TryParse` method instead, depending on your needs.  `ToString("N2")` will return "200.00",  `ToString()` will return "200", and `ToString("C")` will return "$200.00" (in the US).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formatter with the ToString method, as [described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).  I think N0 will work for that.